# how to only change content in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, mobile

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
    <p>First</p>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="navbar" >
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="/test/second.jsp">Second</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

second.jsp

```
<p>Second<p/>
```

I want to change only content div received from server side, while click Second button.

It must no change header and footer.
also support history back, slide animation.

how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use jQuery AJAX convenience method `load()`

```
$('.ui-content').load('/path/to/server/second.jsp');
```

It will make the ajax call and replace the html of the element(s) in selector with response from server

[**load() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax call ,and after its `success` , use `$(".ui-content").html("New content");`

So

`<li><a id="secondAjax" href="javascript:void(0);">Second</a></li>`

```
$("#secondAjax").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'YOUR LOCALHOST PATH/test/second.jsp',
      success:function(data){
        $(".ui-content").html(data);
      }
    });
});
```